# Laravel string to lower on input

Tags: laravel, eloquent

I want to create data and store to db on laravel

```
$kategori= new Kategori;
$kategori->nama_kategori = $request->nama_kategori;
$kategori->save();
```

How do i make `$kategori->nama_kategori` and `$request->nama_kategori` to lower case ?

I've already tried use `strtolower($kategori->nama_kategori)` but it doesn't work

I want if in table already stored value "Hello" and I store again data "hello" it will be error.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 0):

Just use Str::lower();

```
$kategori= new Kategori;
$kategori->nama_kategori = Str:lower($request->nama_kategori);
$kategori->save();
```

Comment: but how to make $kategori->nama_kategori also to lower case ?

Comment: Try to make `dd($kategori);` after that save() line. What do you get?

Comment: I want if in table already stored value "Hello" and I store again data "hello" it will be error.

Answer (score 0):

I think if you use `utf8_general_ci` as a collation to your table with a unique index on the column you can achieve the same thing. because MySQL will be case insensitive and see `Hello` and `hello` as the same thing.

Comment: so how to make Hello and hello as the different thing ? not using utf8_general_ci ?

Comment: In your question you asked to treat them as the same thing in your database .  If you wanna treat them case-sinsitifely  you should use utf8_bin

Comment: thrown an error like this : 
collation "utf8_bin" for encoding "UTF8" does not exist at character 101 .. 

I am using laravel migrations and add collation('utf8_bin') on nama_kategori column

Answer (score 0):

**The better way is to use it on Kategori Model side with Mutator, so that your controller code will look clean**

```
class Kategori extends Model
{

  public function setNamaKategoriAttribute($value)
  {
    $this->attributes['nama_kategori'] = strtolower($value);
  }

}
```